# How does one go about restoring the Windows 8 Boot GUI if one chose Windows Vista as the default before knowing they'd loose the nifty GUI interface?

Tags: windows-8, windows-vista, multi-boot, bootloader

How does one go about restoring the Windows 8 Boot GUI if one chose Windows Vista as the default before knowing they'd loose the nifty GUI interface? I'd rather make Windows 8 Default and choose Vista when I want just to get the mouse capable Boot GUI back.

Comment: Would running MSCONFIG help?

Answer (score 2):

Set Windows 8 as default (via `msconfig`) and run this command from a command prompt with admin rights (elevated):

```
bcdedit /set {current} bootmenupolicy standard
```

Now you should have the new Boot manager back.

**Source:**

http://www.intowindows.com/restore-boot-options-menu-in-windows-8/